# Radio Button Wordpress Only One Choose

Tags: wordpress, button, radio-button

I Want to make radio buttons from form with one choose only. Single Options with

A. Exemple One
B. Exemple Two
C. Exemple Three
D. Exemple Four

If you choose one questions A, you cant to change your opinion. Thanks for help.

http://preview.ipanelthemes.com/fsqm/form-with-latex-options/

Here you have exemple.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be using JavaScript to add an event listener so that when a user clicks on one of the radio options, the script then will set the "disabled" attribute in place.

Given the following HTML:

```
<form>
   <input type="radio" name="creditcard" id="visa">Visa
   <input type="radio" name="creditcard" id="mstrcrd">MasterCard
   <input type="radio" name="creditcard" id="amex">American Express
   <input type="radio" name="creditcard" id="dscvr">Discover
</form>
```

You could use the following JavaScript:

```
var radioInputs = document.getElementsByName("creditcard");
function toggleDisable() {
    for (i=0; i<radioInputs.length; i++) {
        radioInputs[i].disabled = true;
    }
 }

for (i=0; i<radioInputs.length; i++) {
    radioInputs[i].addEventListener('click', toggleDisable, false);
}
```

Keep in mind that the .addEventListener method will not work in IE8 or prior. You will either need to write an if statement checking for the .addEventListener or use jQuery.